# React rendering wrong value when mapping over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am having a very strange issue and was not able to find anyone describing the same problem on the internet. If there is the same issue posted somewhere out there, I apologize for the duplicate question.

I have a "Schedule" represented by an array of objects. Each object within the array represents a "Week" and each Week contains an array of "Sessions".

```
  const schedule = [
    {
      title: "Week 16",
      sessions: [
        {
          sessionName: "Session 1: First Session",
          date: "8/15/2020",
          registrationLink: "Link",
          description: "Description for session 1"
        },
        {
          sessionName: "Session 2: Second Session",
          date: "8/28/2020",
          registrationLink: "AnotherLink",
          description: "Description for session 2"
        }
      ]
    },
  ];
```

I a mapping over the schedule and rendering each week. In each week, I grab the sessions and filter out sessions that have already happened using momentjs. I then map over the upcoming sessions (i.e. sessions that have not yet occurred) and render each session. Each session contains a registration link that allows users to register for the session.

```
const Schedule = ({ schedule }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {schedule.map((week, weekIndex) => {
        const upcomingSessions = week.sessions.filter(
          ({ date }) => moment(date).diff(moment(today)) >= 0
        )
        if (upcomingSessions.length !== 0) {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={weekIndex}>
              {upcomingSessions.map((session, sessionIndex) => {
                return (
                  <Session
                    key={`upcoming-${weekIndex}-${sessionIndex}`}
                    session={session}
                  />
                )
              })}
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        }
        return "";
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

At the time of writing (8/19/2020), in the above example Session 1 would not be rendered because the session already occurred. The bug I am experiencing is that when Session 2 is rendering, it renders with the link from Session 1. No other properties (e.g. sessionName, description, date) are mixed up, only the registrationLink. The best part about this bug? I am not able to replicate it in development.

At first I thought it might be something to do with the `key`s that I provided. I made them more unique by including a part of the registration link in them (not shown in the snippet above).

Next I thought it might have something to do with cacheing, so we changed the `Cache-control` to `no-cache`. That seemed to solve the problem at the time... but I am now getting reports of mixed up registration links again.

So I am reaching out to see if anyone has had a similar issue or if anyone has any insight into what may be happening. Thank you all.

Comment: Try using Promise or async/await inside the map. In your case, `upcomingSessions condition` check should wait for `upcomingSessions filter` to complete.

Comment: Are you sure? I've found other sources that say Array.prototype.filter() is synchronous.

I'm certainly open to trying, but as I mentioned in the description-I can't replicate this bug in development-so I would have to push changes live

Comment: from past experience, when JS code behave differently on prod vs dev, it's usually the minification done during the bundling of the app. Try deploying a version w/o minification to validate if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

So from [Shankar Ganesh Jayaraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1929115/shankar-ganesh-jayaraman)'s comment I went with the idea that maybe the filtering that was happening had something to do with the bug.

I moved `upcomingSessions` to the local state of `Schedule` and set `upcomingSessions` when the component loads. It has fixed the issue, but I honestly can't say why.